# Solving $\frac{\partial}{\partial s} (u(x+as, t+s)) = f(x+as, t+s)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am doing a course on PDEs and I am struggling to understand how to solve this:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s} (u(x+as, t+s) = f(x+as, t+s)$$

The notes say to integrate from $s = -t$ to $s= 0$ and they obtain $$u(x, t) = u(x-at, 0) + \int_{-t}^0 f(x+as, t+s) ds$$ but I don't understand how they have arrived here. This is probably fairly simple, but I'm looking for someone to help me fill in the details.

I am particularly struggling with the arguments on $u$, so how it has gone from $u(x+as, t+s)$ to $u(x, t)$ and how we have obtained the $u(x-at, 0)$ term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the fundamental theorem of analysis. We have 
$$\int_a^b f(s)\,ds = F(b) - F(a) \tag{1}$$
with $F'(s) =f(s)$.

Now introduce the functions $$F_L(s) = u(x+as, t+s)$$ for the left-hand side and  $$f_R(s) = f(x+as, t+s)$$
for the right-hand side.

From $f_L(s)= f_R(s)$, we obtain (from (1) with $a=-t$ and $b=0$)
$$ F_L(0) - F_L(-t) = \int_{-t}^0f_R(s)\,ds = \int_{-t}^0 f(x+as, t+s)\,ds $$
or equivalently
$$ u(x,t) - u(x- a t, 0) = \int_{-t}^0 f(x+as, t+s)\,ds\,.$$